# New Ram, infinite windows repair loop

Tags: windows-7, memory

My laptop is Gateway NV55c38u, the ram usable according to crucial is

> CT5305987
>   DDR3L PC3L-12800 • CL=11 • Unbuffered • NON-ECC • DDR3L-1600 • 1.35V

The one I used is

> Samsung m471b5173bh0-ck0
>   4GB DMS Certified Memory 204 Pin DDR3-1600 PC3-12800 512x64 CL11 1.5V SODIMM

I upgraded bios to the latest version and still having problem with the infinte loop, it did register the 8gb total on bios.

Comment: May be the RAM is bad, try Memtest86: http://www.memtest86.com/

Comment: I see that you used 1.5 V RAM instead of 1.35 V RAM. If you did not remove the RAM already in there, the mis-match in voltages could prevent it from working reliably.

Comment: oh, i didn't notice the voltage difference, I think that maybe what is doing it (both new ram is good)